# draw.String() and fillRect() writing to different positions on JFrame with the same passed coordinates

Tags: java, jframe

I pretty new to Java and I'm trying create a bar graph that takes in 5 values from a text field and creates a bar graph with the 5 values. I have the majority of it working correctly, maybe not in the most efficient way, but I'm running into trouble using drawString(). I'm trying to output the height of each bar at the top of each bar for debugging purposes and because eventually I will need to label the entire y-axis in steps of 10. However, every time I pass the same exact y value, "height", to the draw.String(), it outputs to a different spot than the top left portion of the rectangle. I'm not sure why this is happening. Shouldn't passing identical y values mean the outputs will be at the same height? Any help would be appreciated. I attached a pic of the output I'm getting. While, I did not include it here, I do have two lines of code to draw the x and y axis.

```
 public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    super.paint(g);


    double v1 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField1.getText());
    double v2 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    double v3 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField3.getText());
    double v4 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField4.getText());
    double v5 = Double.parseDouble(jTextField5.getText());

    Graphics pg = jPanel2.getGraphics();

    int[] values = {(int)v1,(int)v2,(int)v3,(int)v4,(int)v5};
    double space = (jPanel2.getHeight()*.09);
    //Space for the bottom
    int spaceY = (int)space;
    int bar;
    double heightPortion;
    int height; 
    double heightCalc;
    double numHeight;
    int numHeight2;

    //5% of the top of the frame is open
   double gap = getHeight()*.05;
   int gapTrunc = (int)gap;

   //Display each value 
    for (int i= 0; i < 5; i++){


    bar = values[i];   

    //Calculate what portion of the max height of a bar each value is   
    heightPortion = 100-bar;
    heightPortion = heightPortion/100;

   //Use 86% of the graph for the bars
    heightCalc = heightPortion *(.86)*jPanel2.getHeight() + gapTrunc;



    height = (int)heightCalc;



    //Debugging
    System.out.println(height);

    //Use different colors for different letters
    if(0<= bar && bar < 20)
        pg.setColor(Color.orange);
    if(20 <= bar && bar < 40)
        pg.setColor(Color.gray);
    if(40 <= bar && bar < 60)
        pg.setColor(Color.yellow);
    if(60 <= bar && bar < 80)
        pg.setColor(Color.blue);
    if(80 <= bar && bar <= 100)
        pg.setColor(Color.red);


    String s = Integer.toString(bar);

    //Draw bar
    pg.fillRect(jPanel2.getWidth()-(jPanel2.getWidth()*(16-
3*i)/20),height,20,jPanel2.getHeight()-height-spaceY);
    //Label bar with value, passing it the same height
    g.drawString(s,jPanel2.getWidth()-(jPanel2.getWidth()*(16-
3*i)/20),height);


    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: You've made a series of fundamental mistakes which seems to suggest that you've not taken the time to read any of the available material.  Start by having a look at [Performing Custom Painting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html) for more information about how custom painting should be done

Comment: Rendering text is a little more complicated then most people think, I would recommend by having a look at [Working with Text APIs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/text/index.html) for more details about how text rendering actually works

Comment: I'm just going to put this out there - but DON'T, EVER, use `getGraphics`, it's now how custom painting works and will cause all sorts of issues which can be avoided by using the painting API correctly

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `drawString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawString-java.lang.String-int-int-) says as follows (emphasis mine):

> Draws the text given by the specified string, using this graphics context's current font and color. **The baseline of the leftmost character** is at position (x, y) in this graphics context's coordinate system.

The [documentation for `fillRect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#fillRect-int-int-int-int-) says as follows (emphasis mine):

> Fills the specified rectangle. **The left** and right edges of the rectangle are at x and x + width - 1. **The top** and bottom edges are at y and y + height - 1. The resulting rectangle covers an area width pixels wide by height pixels tall. The rectangle is filled using the graphics context's current color.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 2 different graphic contexts:

```
public void paint(Graphics g)
{
    Graphics pg = jPanel2.getGraphics();

    pg.fillRect(...);
    g.drawString(s, ...);
```

Use the same context, `g`, the one passed to the paint routine.